# Wrapping images using css relative and absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to stack images invisibly on top of one another within a div so that you can toggle between them. I've got the javascript working but am having problems understanding the various static/absolute/relative css properties.

I've tried to make it so that there is a page title, a few lines of explanatory text, some toggle controls and then the images. 
In the definition of the various image IDs, I've specified the z-order so the images can be stacked within the imagewrapper div. The problem is in the definition of imagewrapper and overlayimage. On my PC it looks fine, but the use of "top" and "left" means that the text is obscured when viewed on a phone or whetever. Can anyone suggest a workaround, please?

The complete code so far is as follows - its just the positioning that is causing trouble; many of the variables and functions are just stubs at present:

```js
var nt = 0;

function togglent() {

  if (nt == 0) {
    document.getElementById("nighttime").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("nighttime").style.opacity = 1;
    nt = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nighttime").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("nighttime").style.opacity = document.getElementById("ntSlider").value;
    nt = 0;
  }

  // when clicked, switch back and forth between nighttime; if nt=1, the nighttime needs to be from the slider value



}

function handleClick(cb) {

    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
      var imgmod = cb.value + "24";

      if (cb.checked) {
        document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity) + 0.1;

        if (cb.value != "backdrop" && cb.value != "aurora") {
          document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity) + 0.1;
        }

        if (document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity >= 1) {
          document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity = 1;

          if (cb.value != "backdrop" && cb.value != "aurora") {
            document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity = 1;
          }

          clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
      } else {
        document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity) - 0.1;
        if (cb.value != "backdrop" && cb.value != "aurora") {
          document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity) - 0.1;
        }

        if (document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity <= 0) {
          document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity = 0;

          if (cb.value != "backdrop" && cb.value != "aurora") {
            document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity = 0;
          }

          clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
      }

    }, 100);

  } // end of handleClick

function showSliderValue(sl) {

  if (sl > 0) {
    document.getElementById("nighttime").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("nighttime").style.opacity = sl;
  } else if (sl == 0) {
    document.getElementById("nighttime").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("nighttime").style.opacity = sl;
  }

}



function alldata(cb) {
  if (cb.checked) {

    document.getElementById("mainindex").style.visibility = "visible";

    document.getElementById("mainindex24").style.visibility = "hidden";

  } else {
    document.getElementById("mainindex").style.visibility = "hidden";

    document.getElementById("mainindex24").style.visibility = "visible";

  }

}
```

```css
.imageWrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.overlayImage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 330;
  left: 0;
}
#nighttime {
  z-index: 10;  /* An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. */
  opacity: 0.0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#background {
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 1.0;
  visibility: visible;
}
#backdrop {
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0.0;
  visibility: visible;
}
#aurora {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1.0;
  visibility: visible;
}
#mainindex {
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 1.0;
  visibility: visible;
}
#mainindex24 {
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 1.0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
input {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageWrapper" onclick='togglent();'>
  <img id="nighttime" class="overlayImage" src="nt.jpg">
  <img id="background" class="overlayImage" src="background.jpg">
  <img id="backdrop" class="overlayImage" src="Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg">
  <img id="aurora" class="overlayImage" src="aurora.png">
</div>
<p>

  <form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick='handleClick(this);' value="backdrop" checked><span style="color: black;">Backdrop</span>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick='handleClick(this);' value="aurora" checked>
  </form>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would include all the html, css and javascript for your question. That way when some one answers it they will not have to guess what you meant in the paragraph below your posted code.

Comment: OK, no problem. I've added more of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Among the changes done, the most relevant to the OP's question is:

```
  .imageWrapper {
      position: relative;
      height: auto;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    .overlayImage {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10vh;
      left: 0;
    }
```

By using relative units of measurements such as percentages (`%`), `em`s, `rem`s, viewport height and width (`vh` and `vw`), we can get enough elasticity to avoid overlaps of critical areas in a range of different dimensions.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }
    .imageWrapper {
      position: relative;
      height: auto;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    .overlayImage {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10vh;
      left: 0;
    }
    #nighttime {
      z-index: 10;
      opacity: 0.0;
    }
    #background {
      z-index: -2;
      opacity: 1.0;
    }
    #backdrop {
      z-index: 0;
      opacity: 0.0;
    }
    #aurora {
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 1.0;
    }
    #mainindex {
      z-index: 3;
      opacity: 1.0;
    }
    #mainindex24 {
      z-index: 3;
      opacity: 1.0;
    }
    input {
      margin: 10px 0;
      display: none;
    }
    fieldset {
      width: 720px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      min-height: 20px;
    }
    img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 720px;
      height: auto;
    }
    label input + span {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      background: rgba(255, 0, 128, .4);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    label input:checked + span {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .4);
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="imageWrapper" onclick='togglent();'>
    <img id="nighttime" class="overlayImage" src="http://orig15.deviantart.net/8697/f/2016/047/5/c/windows_nt_by_gpolydoros-d7k5mry.png">
    <img id="background" class="overlayImage" src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/masseffect/images/1/1f/Background.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20121030013132">
    <img id="backdrop" class="overlayImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Equirectangular_projection_SW.jpg">
    <img id="aurora" class="overlayImage" src="http://www.luostonporosafarit.fi/media/wwwkuvat/porokuvia_2014/northern_lights.jpg.jpg">
  </div>

  <form action="">
    <fieldset>
      <label>Back
        <input type="checkbox" onclick='handleClick(this);' value="backdrop" checked>
        <span></span>
      </label>


      <label>drop
        <input type="checkbox" onclick='handleClick(this);' value="aurora" checked>
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <script>
    var nt = 0;

    function togglent() {

      if (nt === 0) {
        document.getElementById("nighttime").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("nighttime").style.opacity = 1;
        nt = 1;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("nighttime").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("nighttime").style.opacity = document.getElementById("ntSlider").value;
        nt = 0;
      }

      // when clicked, switch back and forth between nighttime; if nt=1, the nighttime needs to be from the slider value



    }

    function handleClick(cb) {

        var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
          var imgmod = cb.value + "24";

          if (cb.checked) {
            document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity) + 0.1;

            if (cb.value != "backdrop" && cb.value != "aurora") {
              document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity) + 0.1;
            }

            if (document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity >= 1) {
              document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity = 1;

              if (cb.value != "backdrop" && cb.value != "aurora") {
                document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity = 1;
              }

              clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
          } else {
            document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity) - 0.1;
            if (cb.value != "backdrop" && cb.value != "aurora") {
              document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity = parseFloat(document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity) - 0.1;
            }

            if (document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity <= 0) {
              document.getElementById(cb.value).style.opacity = 0;

              if (cb.value != "backdrop" && cb.value != "aurora") {
                document.getElementById(imgmod).style.opacity = 0;
              }

              clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
          }

        }, 100);

      } // end of handleClick

    function showSliderValue(sl) {

      if (sl > 0) {
        document.getElementById("nighttime").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("nighttime").style.opacity = sl;
      } else if (sl == 0) {
        document.getElementById("nighttime").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("nighttime").style.opacity = sl;
      }

    }



    function alldata(cb) {
      if (cb.checked) {

        document.getElementById("mainindex").style.visibility = "visible";

        document.getElementById("mainindex24").style.visibility = "hidden";

      } else {
        document.getElementById("mainindex").style.visibility = "hidden";

        document.getElementById("mainindex24").style.visibility = "visible";

      }

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```